# On what instance of class delegate gets invoked?

Tags: c#, events, delegates

Consider this code,

```
public class A
{
     //...
     void f()
     {  
          B b = new B();
          b.SomeEvent += this.SomeMethod;
     }
     void SomeMethod() {}
 }

 public class B
 {
     //...

     public event SomeEventHandler SomeEvent;

     void h()
     {  
          if ( SomeEvent != null )
          {
               SomeEvent.invoke();
          }
     }
 }
```

In this code snippet, `SomeEvent.invoke()` actually invokes `SomeMethod()` of class `A`. So at this point, I've few questions:

- On what instance of `A`, `SomeMethod` gets invoked? How does `B` know the instance on which the delegate to be invoked? How does CLR  work here?
- Also, `SomeMethod` is a *private* method, then how come `B` is able to invoke this method from outside of the class `A`?

EDIT:

After reading first few answers, I came to know that `Delegate` has a `Target` property on which delegate gets invoked. But I couldn't really understand as to at exactly what step this `Target` property is set? Who set it? When I write `b.SomeEvent += this.SomeMethod;`, does it set the `Target` property as well?  How exactly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 b.SomeEvent += this.SomeMethod
```

There's a lot of sugar here that prevents you from seeing what is really happening.  Written out, it resembles this:

```
 b.SomeEvent.add(new MulticastDelegate(this, SomeMethod));     // not legal code
```

Where add() is the add accessor for the event, the compiler auto-generates one when you don't declare your own explicitly.  The first argument to the delegate constructor is the object instance that you are asking about, the delegate object's Target property.  Note that this has side-effects, the event subscription keeps a reference to your `b` object.  Which prevents it from getting garbage collected, that would be rather bad when the event is invoked.

That can also be a problem, you can unintentionally leak the object reference.  There's no good way in your code to un-subscribe the event handler so the A object is going to live as long as the B object on which you called h().

Comment: Finally one post...this tells me something I was looking for. +1

Answer (score 2):

The delegate contains the target reference to call the method on. You can examine this with the `Delegate.Target` property. In this case it will be called on the instance which `f` is called on. (It's null if you're calling a static method.)

As for the privacy - that's just one of the features of delegates. You can only *create* the delegate within code which has access to a private method, but you can *run* it anywhere. Think of this as being like implementing an interface by just calling a private method from the public interface implementation.

Comment: Jon : I edited my question. Please see the EDIT. I want to understand it in-depth.

Comment: BTW, I've bought your book, probably you remember I had told you when I ordered for it. So if you've discussed this thing in your book, please do tell me the chapter/section so that I'll read this myself, in detail.

Comment: @Nawaz: Chapter 2 contains quite a bit about delegates, yes. Enjoy :)

Comment: Haha...right now I'm at section `2.2.2 When is C# 1's type system not rich enough?`. Thanks for writing such a wonderful book. Probably you might have guessed that this book made me ask this question. Maybe, I should have some patience!

Answer (score 2):

> On what instance of A, SomeMethod gets invoked? How does B know the instance on which the delegate to be invoked? How does CLR work here?

The delegate actually contains a reference to the actual instance.  This will cause it to invoke on the specific instance on which it was called.

> Also, SomeMethod is a private method, then how come B is able to invoke this method from outside of the class A?

It doesn't execute the method directly - it executes the *delegate*.  There's a difference here - the private constraint only applies to the method, but since the class itself creates the delegate, it has access to the method, so everything works fine.

Answer (score 1):

- Whatever instance was used when attaching to the event
- Because `A` passed a delegate representation to it outside of the class.

A particular `Delegate` instance has a `Target` property; this represents the instance that will be used when invoking the delegate.